# What are all the meteorite looking objects around starman?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy

[image: Starman Meteorites]

Here is the video [Starman Meteorites](https://www.reddit.com/user/LeatherUnderstanding/comments/7vw5k9/does_anybody_know_what_those_things_in_the/)

Comment: It may be dust on the camera's sensor or a bad pixel of the image sensor. Does it change position within the image?

Comment: No, it doesn't change position with the image, the change at different speeds. And also, they can be seen behind the windshield so I don't think it's a bad camera sensor. You can take a closer look in the video https://www.reddit.com/user/LeatherUnderstanding/comments/7vw5k9/does_anybody_know_what_those_things_in_the/